# Can not see values of locals in QtCreator debug mode

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I am working on a `Qt5.7.0` (using `C++ 4.9.1`) project for which I am using `QtCreator 4.1.0` as IDE. When running the application in `debug` mode, I am trying to find out the values of `Locals and Expressions` on a `BreakPoint`. But I can't see the values . It shows some values which are not so important for me (Screenshot added for reference).

[image]

As you can see, there are some `QString`s, values of which are not being shown, instead it's showing the addresses, I think. Same things also happening even for `int`.

Is there any way to fix this?

FYI, it used to be perfect even 2 days ago. I don't know what got changed accidentally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Menu Bar, Go to `Tools`, the `Options`. Then select `Debugger` in the Left Pane. Now select `Locals and Expressions` Tab. I think, you have `Use Debugger Help` Checkbox unchecked.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tDJb.png)

Check this checkbox. I think, the problem will be solved.

Comment: I have the same issue on Mac and it doesn't help. Also, I'd like to use custom helpers, so that won't help. Any other idea?

Comment: Mine changed from pointer value to <not accessible>...  I had to stick to the trustworthy method for debugging strings: good old printf().  It's never failed me for 20 years.